# Rails SQL datetime comparing fails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am trying to run a comparison on datetime field. With timezone, the value gets treated as a string.

DB: MS SQL

```
MyTable.find_by_sql("select * from my_table where my_date > '2012-02-15 16:07:32 UTC'")

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

If I remove the timezone, it returns results.

```
MyTable.find_by_sql("select * from my_table where my_date > '2012-02-15 16:07:32'")
```

How can I do this comparison with `'2012-02-15 16:07:32 UTC'`?
I need to use find_by_sql (fetching data from a different DB. Can't use the rails sql queries).
Thanks!

Comment: You need to show your rails code and it would also be helpful to state which database server you are using. (I'm guessing MS SQL Server).

Comment: @BenTrewern I have updated the post. Does that help?

Comment: Where are you getting the string with timezone from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the datetime using:

```
a_datetime = DateTime.strptime('2012-02-15 16:07:32 UTC', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

then format the date using something like:

```
datetime_str = a_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

and do your find with:

```
MyTable.find_by_sql("select * from my_table where my_date > '#{datetime_str}'")
```

I haven't tested any of this but should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're calling `to_s` on a datetime field resulting in '2012-02-15 16:07:32 UTC'?

Try calling `to_s(:db)` instead for the database-friendly version.